# Daemon and View both accessing SQLite Database at the same time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, concurrency, locking

I have a rake task running as daemon that scrapes thousands of podcast rss feeds for new episodes.  If it finds a new episode, it writes it to the database.  If it finds a change to an old episode, it writes that change to the database.  This daemon runs constantly.

Now let's say that a user goes to a page for a particular podcast.  I have an ajax polling (comet) process in my view that will fetch new episodes for the given podcast with delayed_job.

Right now I can only run one of these at a time.  I can either run the daemon or let the user trigger the delayed_job process.  I am new to Rails and don't really understand how to enable the concurrency I need.  I haven't posted any code here because my question is really conceptual at this point.  How would one design an application to be able to handle this kind of concurrency?

I'm under the impression that switching to MySQL might alleviate some of these issues, however, I feel like I'm missing a key piece of the puzzle here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The piece you're missing is this. SQLite is a file-based database, meaning that when a process accesses it, it locks the file. This is why you can only do one thing at a time, whether that's your daemon updating data or the view accessing it.

The solution is to move to a proper database, like MySQL as you suggested. You've far outgrown the capabilities of SQLite, it's not meant to be used the way you're using it.

Comment: Thank you Srdjan Pejic.  I was hoping that was the answer.  Time to take off the training wheels, I suppose.